# Fill EditorFor Field

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, html-helper, editorfor

I'm trying to fill a editorfor field with a default value. Please help

My Code:

```
<div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Country)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Country)
</div>
```

The model is created by entity framework throughmy SQL database.

Comment: can you be little more specific with your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just use the model's constructor?

```
public class CustomerViewModel
{
    public string Country { get; set; }

    public CustomerViewModel()
    {
        this.Country = "Default value";
    }
}
```